# JPA CONCATE when used with IN operator throws Exception

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, openjpa

I am trying to run a complex JPQL QUERY which doesn't throws Exception and works weirdly.

So here is my query

```
SELECT b.pk.col1, b.pk.col2
  FROM table1 b
 WHERE     b.pk.col2 IN ('someString')
       AND b.pk.col3 IN (0, 1, 2)
       AND b.pk.sdate < :now
       AND b.edate > :now
       AND b.col4 = 1
       AND EXISTS
              (SELECT a.cmid
                 FROM table2 a
                WHERE a.col1 = 5 AND a.col2 = b.pk.col1)
       AND b.pk.col1 NOT IN
              (SELECT a.pk.col1
                 FROM table3 a
                WHERE CONCAT (a.pk.tagid, 'ayush') IN ('1ayush'))
```

For Some Reason it throws error on Last line. Here is the error

> Exception data:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: 
>       Encountered "b . pk . col1 NOT IN ( select a . pk . col1 FROM Table3 a where CONCAT ( a . pk . tagId , \'ayush\' ) IN 
>       (" at character 249, but expected: ["(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", ":", "<", "<=", "<>", "=", ">", ">=", "?", "ABS", "ALL", "AND", "ANY", "AS", "ASC", "AVG", 
>       "BETWEEN", "BOTH", "BY", "CONCAT", "COUNT", "CURRENT_DATE", "CURRENT_TIME", "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", "DELETE", "DESC", "DISTINCT", "EMPTY", "ESCAPE", "EXISTS", "FETCH", "FROM", 
>       "GROUP", "HAVING", "IN", "INNER", "IS", "JOIN", "LEADING", "LEFT", "LENGTH", "LIKE", "LOCATE", "LOWER", 
>       "MAX", "MEMBER", "MIN", "MOD", "NEW", "NOT", "NULL", "OBJECT", "OF", "OR", "ORDER", "OUTER", "SELECT", "SET", "SIZE", "SOME", "SQRT", "SUBSTRING", "SUM", "TRAILING", "TRIM", "UPDATE", "UPPER", "WHERE", , , , , ].

I have broken the query into multiple lines for the clarity :

This is the query in one single line

```
    SELECT b.pk.col1, b.pk.col2
  FROM table1 b
 WHERE     b.pk.col2 IN ('someString')
       AND b.pk.col3 IN (0, 1, 2)
       AND b.pk.sdate < :now
       AND b.edate > :now
       AND b.col4 = 1
       AND EXISTS
              (SELECT a.cmid
                 FROM table2 a
                WHERE a.col1 = 5 AND a.col2 = b.pk.col1)
       AND b.pk.col1 NOT IN
              (SELECT a.pk.col1
                 FROM table3 a
                WHERE CONCAT (a.pk.tagid, 'ayush') IN ('1ayush'))
```

I forgot to mention that if I try to use  `=` instead of `IN`, the query works, however this was a demo query and I actually have to use a List there

**EDIT** :
This my new JPA QUERY to which I give a Collection rather than some hard coded value

```
SELECT b.pk.col1, b.pk.col2
  FROM table1 b
 WHERE     b.pk.col2 IN ('someString')
       AND b.pk.col3 IN (0, 1, 2)
       AND b.pk.sdate < :now
       AND b.edate > :now
       AND b.col4 = 1
       AND EXISTS
              (SELECT a.cmid
                 FROM table2 a
                WHERE a.col1 = 5 AND a.col2 = b.pk.col1)
       AND (b.pk.col1 NOT IN
               (SELECT a.pk.col1
                  FROM table3 a
                 WHERE CONCAT (a.pk.tagid, 'ayush') IN (:somelist)))
```

And I still get the same Exception

> Exception data:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Encountered "b . pk . col1 NOT IN ( select a . pk . col1 FROM Table3 a where CONCAT ( a . pk . tagId , \'ayush\' ) IN" at character 249, but expected: ["(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", ":", "<", "<=", "<>", "=", ">", ">=", "?", "ABS", "ALL", "AND", "ANY", "AS", "ASC", "AVG", "BETWEEN", "BOTH", "BY", "CONCAT", "COUNT", "CURRENT_DATE", "CURRENT_TIME", "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", "DELETE", "DESC", "DISTINCT", "EMPTY", "ESCAPE", "EXISTS", "FETCH", "FROM", "GROUP", "HAVING", "IN", "INNER", "IS", "JOIN", "LEADING", "LEFT", "LENGTH", "LIKE", "LOCATE", "LOWER", "MAX", "MEMBER", "MIN", "MOD", "NEW", "NOT", "NULL", "OBJECT", "OF", "OR", "ORDER", "OUTER", "SELECT", "SET", "SIZE", "SOME", "SQRT", "SUBSTRING", "SUM", "TRAILING", "TRIM", "UPDATE", "UPPER", "WHERE", , , , , ].
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.generateParseException(JPQL.java:9566)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.jj_consume_token(JPQL.java:9443)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.conditional_primary(JPQL.java:1947)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.conditional_factor(JPQL.java:1925)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.conditional_term(JPQL.java:1791)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.conditional_expression(JPQL.java:1753)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.conditional_primary(JPQL.java:1942)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.conditional_factor(JPQL.java:1925)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.conditional_term(JPQL.java:1791)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.conditional_term(JPQL.java:1804)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.conditional_term(JPQL.java:1804)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.conditional_term(JPQL.java:1804)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.conditional_term(JPQL.java:1804)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.conditional_term(JPQL.java:1804)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.conditional_term(JPQL.java:1804)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.conditional_expression(JPQL.java:1753)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.where_clause(JPQL.java:1556)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.select_statement(JPQL.java:91)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.parseQuery(JPQL.java:63)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder$ParsedJPQL.parse(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:1740)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder$ParsedJPQL.(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:1727)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLParser.parse(JPQLParser.java:48)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery.newCompilation(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:152)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.newCompilation(QueryImpl.java:657)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compilationFromCache(QueryImpl.java:639)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForCompilation(QueryImpl.java:605)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForExecutor(QueryImpl.java:667)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.getOperation(QueryImpl.java:1492)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.getOperation(DelegatingQuery.java:123)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:243)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:294)

Answer (score 0):

`"xxx IN yyy"` should be "`{someValue} IN {someCollection}`". You don't have a collection on the right hand side, hence the exception. If your query really does now have a collection on the right hand side (which it doesn't in your post) and you still get an exception then post the actual exception+stack trace. If the "xxx" and "yyy" are supposed to be equal, then you use "="